# Remove element selectors from css using regex

Tags: c#, css, regex

I have a minified CSS string that contains class selectors (the ones leaded by a dot) as well as element selectors (not leaded by a dot).

```css
tr {...}.style0 {...}.style1 {...}col {...}.style2 {...}.style3 {...}
```

I want to remove all `element selectors` from the string so that the result looks like the following:

```css
.style0 {...}.style1 {...}.style2 {...}.style3 {...}
```

So i need a regular expression that matches all element selectors so i can replace them with an empty string.

I already tried working with the negative lookahead but as my regex knowledge is way too basic i couldnt get it to work.

The regular expression i tried was `(?!\.).*?{.*?}` but this just ignores the dots on matching...

I have a link [here](https://regex101.com/r/jbYpMX/1) for testing the regular expression with my example from above.

Comment: Maybe something like this [`(?<=}|^)\s*+[^.].*?\s*{[\s\S]*?}`](https://regex101.com/r/jbYpMX/3) will get you going. But beware of nested braces. And if it will be done programmatically - consider using css parser instead.

Comment: If you simply remove them you will likely produce invalid CSS as a result. Example: `.hi{display: block;}div{font-weidght:16px}span{display:block;}` will produce ``.hi{display: block;} {font-weidght:16px} {display:block;}``  Answer posters should be aware of this.

Comment: I also want to remove the braces behind obvoiusly (see disired result)

Comment: @CrazyEight, it will also be helpful, if you [edit] question and add language/tool being used for this.

Comment: I'm currently only testing around with Regex101. But it should be coded in C# .NET 6

Comment: I came up with a half-baked solution that can handle both quoted strings and nested blocks (yes, this feature is about to be widely supported): [`(?<=}|^)\s*[^.\s]\S*?\s*(?<brace>{)(?:(?<quote>')(?:\\.|(?!\k<quote>).)\k<quote>|.)*?(?<-brace>})`](https://regex101.com/r/jbYpMX/5). This proves nothing but that CSS should be dealt with using full-fledged parsers instead of regex.

Comment: Is that really necessary to handle nested braces as i just want to delete everything that is not leaded by a dot... So isnt it just important to match everything before those curly braces and the curly braces themselves?

Comment: If this is one-time and you know how the structure looks like, feel free to skip the balancing groups part (or anything you feel unnecessary), but if not, then, as suggested above, the best way is to go with a parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to @markalex and @insync i now use

```
(?<=}|^)\s*[^.].*?{.*?}
```

to match the element selectors and delete them.

Thanks!